# calculate limit of series

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

While getting limit of infinite series I have came to next expession $$ \lim_{k \to \infty}  \frac{1}{\frac{3^k}{k^2}}
$$ and do not know how to procede with $$ \lim_{k \to \infty} {3^k} $$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve this without knowledge of which function grows faster, by using L'Hospital rule twice:

$$ \lim_{k \to \infty}  \frac{1}{\frac{3^k}{k^2}} = 
   \lim_{k \to \infty}  \frac{k^2}{3^k} = 
   \lim_{k \to \infty}  \frac{2k}{3^k \ln 3} = 
   \lim_{k \to \infty}  \frac{2}{3^k (\ln 3)^2} = 0
$$

You can read on wikipedia more on [L'Hospital rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule).

Comment: The $\infty$ should be a $0$.

Comment: is not it $$ \lim_{k \to \infty}  \frac{2}{3^k (\ln 3)^2}=\lim_{k \to \infty}  \frac{2}{\infty}=0$$

Comment: Yeah, my mistake, I corrected it.

Answer (score 3):

$$ \lim_{k \to \infty}  \frac{1}{\frac{3^k}{k^2}}= \lim_{k \to \infty}  \frac{k^2}{3^k}=0$$ since $3^k\to\infty$ more fastly than $k^2$

Answer (score 2):

We have 
$$ \lim_{k \to \infty}  \frac{1}{\frac{3^k}{k^2}}= 
\lim_{k \to \infty}  \frac{k^2}{3^k}
$$ 
Now note that ( by binomial theorem )
$$
3^k=(2+1)^k=2^k+k(2)^{k-1}+\frac{k(k-1)}{2}(2)^{k-2}+\frac{k(k-2)(k-3)}{6}(2)^{k-3}+
\dots
+\frac{k(k-2)(k-3)}{6}(2)^{3}+\frac{k(k-1)}{2}(2)^{2}+k(2)^1+1\geq k^3
$$ 
implies $\frac{k^2}{3^k}\leq \frac{k^2}{k^3}=\frac{1}{k}$. The result then follows from the sandwich theorem applied on inequality: 
$$
0\leq\frac{k^2}{3^k}\leq \frac{1}{k}.
$$